# Commands to run function keys from command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, 64-bit

Are there commands to invoke function key commands from a command prompt?  I would like to script something that I can't find command line options for.  Also, I don't want to install another app, like autohotkey, etc.

Windows 7 Home Premium, 64 bit

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps specify what it is you're trying to do?  There may be a better way (i.e.: PowerShell, as suggested by @MarkSowul).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can whip up a VBScript and use SendKeys.  Then you use cscript myscript.vbs.  Example: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine26.htm.  This doesn't use function keys but that's just e.g. {F4}.  More info on what you can do here: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/automate-tasks-with-windows-script-hosts-sendkeys-method/1056137

You could also use PowerShell: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most elegant answer to your question, but I'll introduce you to it as you may find it a pragmatic solution to what you're doing or useful elsewhere.  Look at http://www.autohotkey.com/ This program is more about using a script that performs certain tasks when it detects things like a keypress or mouse movement, but I'm sure you could write a script that will initiate the sending of keys.  You'll also find a bunch of useful prewritten scripts on their site.